# convert simlpe dataframe to multi index column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, multi-index

I have a data-frame of stock features and price, with 26 columns in name df_prc_RI3.( like image)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAqTW.png)

I want to convert it to multi index columns  with level[ stack name].

```
    col = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ ['stack  name'],df_prc_RI3.columns])

    ddf = pd.DataFrame(df_prc_RI3, columns=col)
```

But my problem is that…  values of rows disappear … and they convert  to Nan, after converting, like photo !!!.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeVg7.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
df_prc_RI3.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([ ['stack  name'],df_prc_RI3.columns])
print (df_prc_RI3)
```

Comment: thanks alot....it works.....but what was problem with my code? you merge two lines of my code in one line. .. i did yours , but in two lines..

Comment: @zanjanvh - problem is if use DataFrame constructor there is different original columns with new columns, values not matched so created NaNs